# Openstack nodes with external network only

Tags: openstack

I have few dedicated servers with static external IPs each.
Can I use them to run OpenStack with enough security?
It is not possible to connect them all with LAN, but each have 1Gbps connection to the Internet. Basically majority of this machines are located in this same DC, so transfer speeds between them are awesome.

Comment: Define "enough security"?

Comment: At least as default solution (behind LAN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer, you won't have security because you don't have the proper requirements.  If you did, you would be able to firewall the servers to prevent them from reaching anything except your private network, sending all the external data through a gateway.

Extra info: A 1GB connection on a hypervisor will be way too small to support multiple vm instances on the host.  They would all share the single 1G interface if they are active at the same time.

It sounds like your hardware isn't really useful as cloud resource to run vms.